# iPhone 5c weather app can't change default city

Tags: iphone

The city at the top cannot be deleted & I cannot move another city to the top. Only the locations beneath the top one can be moved or deleted. So how do I delete the wrong location at the top. My location services are on.

Comment: The one at the top should be your current location and hence can't be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable Location service for Weather application.

Settings > Privacy > Location Services - toggle Weather from Always to Never.

'Current Location' vanishes from the Weather app.

Comment: How does that change the default?

Comment: It does actually remove the 'current location' in Weather - though it would help if the answer included that info ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin such a good edit. You've earned liveder a reversal and yourself my continuing thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Location Services thinks you are in the wrong city, then try temporarily disabling WiFi & Bluetooth & see if it can pick up the correct location over your 3G/4G data connection.

WiFi positioning is done by checking which known WiFi transmitters are in range - you don't have to connect to them, just be able to 'see' them.

WiFi locations are gathered in a rather manual & seemingly old-school method by actually driving around, picking up & logging the positions of all WiFi signals.
This isn't any particular security concern, it's the equivalent of Google logging your [& everyone else's] house address to make Google Maps more accurate.
As you can imagine, even if this is not done by just one guy in his old pickup truck, it takes some time to log all locations & any changes since the last log.

This means that if Mr Smith moves from London to Los Angeles & takes his WiFi extenders with him, for a time anyone who can see his WiFi signal in LA is going to be incorrectly 'located' in London instead, until the system shakes itself out.

Anecdotally - last month my ISP changed my (usually unchanging) IP address to an entirely different class A address… & as a result I spent 2 weeks 'living' in Bristol instead of London ;)